# Is it permissible to draw as hobby?what about hanging pictures?

Tags: halal-haram, art

Assalamualaikum,I love to paint and draw.I want to earn money by painting.I know it's not allowed to draw animals,human,creatures with soul.But can I draw natural scenes or cities,flowers etc.as hobby? Can I also sell them and hang in the wall? Please,tell me if it will be halal or not and tell me about hanging pictures which doesn't have any animate creatures in themI love painting nature and flowers.its my hobby.

Comment: If there's no animate stuff in your painting the argument is simple...yes, without a doubt, you can paint and sell drawing of inanimate objects.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm happy now X3

Answer (score 1):

It is not Haram because prophet (PBUH)didn't forbade us to draw non living things. Allah knows the best

Comment: Thank you brother for the information